# Removing Unwanted Buttons (Hide, Reset, Unpin, Show) Below Material-React-Table in my Project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am encountering an issue while using Material-React-Table library. In my project, I have integrated the table, but there are four buttons displayed below it: "Hide all," "reset order," "unpin all," and "show all." These buttons are not necessary for my use case and are taking up unnecessary space.

I've checked the documentation for Material-React-Table, but I couldn't find any information about how to remove these buttons through the provided props. I would like to know if there is a way to customize the table's rendering and exclude these buttons from being displayed.

I have also looked into the CSS and component structure, but I couldn't identify a straightforward way to achieve this. If anyone has encountered a similar situation or knows how to address this, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here's a screenshot of the buttons I'm referring to:
Screenshot

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';
import useTableESSimple from 'components/MRTTable/Hooks/useTableESSimple';
import AllDialogs from 'components/MRTTable/Common/Dialog'
import { tableController } from "hookstate/tableController";
import { SCHEMA } from "./Schema";

function MRTTable({ tableKey, name }) {
  const meta = SCHEMA[name]
  tableKey = tableKey || name // table key should be different if two tables with same name exist in same screen.
  tableController(tableKey).initialize(tableKey, meta);
  const { tableProps, tablePropsState, initialized, classes } = useTableESSimple(tableKey);

  if (!initialized) return null;

  return (
    <div className={classes.table}>
      <MaterialReactTable
        {...tableProps}
        state={{
          ...tablePropsState,
        }}
      />
      <AllDialogs />
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(MRTTable);
```

```
type here
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Material-React-Table did not provide a way to hide those buttons, so I've come up with global CSS solution.

```
.MuiModal-root > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiMenu-list > div > button {
  display: none;
}

.MuiModal-root > .MuiPaper-root > .MuiMenu-list > div > button {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or is this an attempt to add more information to your question? If the former, please [edit] your answer to add more details about how this code solved the problem. If the latter, please delete this answer and add this to your question instead.